# how to do progress bar before webview is ready?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an app with WebView, with HTML code iframe.
The WebView url change by the menu and it's take few second's.
I want create ProgressBar before the WebView is ready to use. How I can do it?

Note:

I will very happy if you give me reviews about the way that I checked the menu value

This is my code in PasteBin:
http://pastebin.com/6gXZxvds

Or here:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String[] menu;
    DrawerLayout dLayout;
    ListView dList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        menu = new String[]{"home","soccer","basketball"};
        dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu);
        dList.setAdapter(adapter);
        dList.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
        dList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {

                dLayout.closeDrawers();         
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("Menu", menu[position]);
                Fragment detail = new DetailFragment();
                detail.setArguments(args);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();       
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, detail).commit();

            }

        });

    }



}
```

DetailFragment:

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    //TextView text;
    String str;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle args) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_detail_fragment, container, false);
        String menu = getArguments().getString("Menu");
        /*text= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail);
        text.setText(menu);*/

        if(menu.equals("home"))
        {
            str = "<iframe src='http://www.fcbj.co.il/' style='min-height: 100%; width: 100%; border: 0px;'></iframe>";
        }
        else if (menu.equals("soccer")) {
            str = "<iframe src='http://www.fcbj.co.il/News/' style='min-height: 100%; width: 100%; border: 0px;'></iframe>";
        }
        else if(menu.equals("basketball"))
        {
            str = "<iframe src='http://www.fcbj.co.il/basketball/News/' style='min-height: 100%; width: 100%; border: 0px;'></iframe>";
        }

        WebView browser =(WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webPage);
        WebSettings settings    =   browser.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.loadData(str,"text/html","UTF-8");


        return view;
    }


}
```

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to set WebChromeClient to webview :

```
browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
     @Override
     public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
         super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
         // change webview progress here                 
     }
});
```